# Ссылка на сайт в профиле не поддерживает кириллицу

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника, ссылки, кириллица

Недавно попытался добавить в свой профиль в качестве ссылки на сайт страницу на LinkedIn, путь к которой содержит кириллические символы (к примеру, такой [https://www.linkedin.com/in/любые-буквы-xxx000](https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-xxx000)).

> [image: ссылка на сайт]

Однако после сохранения изменений я заметил, что данные символы не отображаются.

> [image: итоговая ссылка]

Является ли это ошибкой сайта?

Comment: Конкретную разметку покажи.

Comment: Насколько я понял проблема возникает с любым адресом, если в нём есть кириллические символы.

Comment: А разметка-то какая?

Comment: Вставлять ссылку с декодированными символами не пробовали? `https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-xxx000`, например так: [ вид с кириллицей ] ( вид декодированный) типа так: [https://www.linkedin.com/in/любые-буквы-xxx000](https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-xxx000)

Comment: @AK речь про секцию конкретно для адреса сайта, там нет markdown.

Comment: @alexolut Да не, всё нормально теперь, надо было просто адрес декодировать.

Comment: @AK Спасибо за помощь !!!

Comment: @Qwertiy И без разметки теперь понятно, где была проблема.

Comment: @RomanPodymov должно и без декодирования поддерживать, как в браузере. Так что это баг. Правда фиксить его точно скоро не будут.

Comment: @alexolut Хотя бы какой-то есть способ решения, и то хорошо.

Comment: Запилил [баг-репорт на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311783/339911).

Comment: @alexolut, ну для сайта-то пофиксили, похоже - раньше тоже не работало.

Comment: @Qwertiy где/что пофиксили?

Comment: @alexolut, посмотри, как в тексте вопроса написана ссылка - раньше такое не работало, значит пофиксили.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю, никогда так не писал. Но вот [другой баг со ссылками](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287563/339911) по-прежнему имеет место быть. И [ещё один](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301176/339911).